# strings in a list not properly being added to an empty string

Tags: python-2.7, calculator

Im making a calculator program, and I'm currently trying to get the user's input into a string. I was able to create a list based on the buttons they pressed. So if they pressed 5, the string would be '5', and if they pressed 8 after, it would be '58', etc. So for each time the person presses the button, I have that number added to a list, so in the last example the list would be ['5','8']. Im trying to get those into a string together, '58', but am having issues.

```
from Tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.configure(bg="gray")
root.title("Calculator")

typed_num=[]

def button_command(number):
    typed_num.append(str(number))

    string_num=''
    for val in typed_num:
        string_num+=typed_num
    print string_num


startx=20
starty=60

one_button=Button(root, text="1", command=lambda:button_command(1), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx, y=starty)
two_button=Button(root, text="2", command=lambda:button_command(2), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+60, y=starty)
three_button=Button(root, text="3", command=lambda:button_command(3), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+120, y=starty)
four_button=Button(root, text="4", command=lambda:button_command(4), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx, y=starty+60)
five_button=Button(root, text="5", command=lambda:button_command(5), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+60, y=starty+60)
six_button=Button(root, text="6", command=lambda:button_command(6), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+120, y=starty+60)
seven_button=Button(root, text="7", command=lambda:button_command(7), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx, y=starty+120)
eight_button=Button(root, text="8", command=lambda:button_command(8), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+60, y=starty+120)
nine_button=Button(root, text="9", command=lambda:button_command(9), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+120, y=starty+120)
zero_button=Button(root, text="0", command=lambda:button_command(0), highlightbackground='gray').place(x=startx+60, y=starty+180)


root.mainloop()
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! The error returned is:TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: change `string_num+=typed_num` to `string_num+=val`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting this concatenation here: `string_num+=typed_num`. You can use append if you want to add an item to list such as typed_num.append(string_num). You tried to add a list to a string, you can add a string to a list however. "+" can be also used but the other way around

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you want to add a list with a string, that operation is not possible, I think you want to do is concatenate for them you must change:

```
string_num+=typed_num
```

to

```
string_num+=val
```

A simple way to concatenate a string list is to join, for this it changes:

```
string_num=''
for val in typed_num:
    string_num+=typed_num
print string_num
```

to:

```
print "".join(typed_num)
```